# How am I able to display the largest and the smallest number from the array of the user's input?

Tags: java, arrays

Can somebody help me what's wrong with my codes I'm having trouble with the displaying the largest and the smallest part in the array. Sorry I'm completely new with java. Thanks a bunch

```
package problem6;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
   int input;
   int min = 0;
   int max = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);   
    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
    input = keyboard.nextInt();

    int array[] = new int[input]; 

        for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) {
           System.out.println("Enter number: ");
           array[i] = keyboard.nextInt(); 
        }  

        {   
            if (input > max)   
            {   
                max = input;  
            } 
            else if (input <= min)   
            {   
                min = input;   
            }     
        }   
        System.out.print("\nLargest: " + max);   
        System.out.print("\nSmallest:" + min); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: You have extra pair of braces! remove those extra braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors were

1. an extra pair of braces, and 2. comparing input-size instead of array elements with min and max.

The probable working code is shown below :-

```
package problem6;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
   int input;
   int min = 0;
   int max = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);   
    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
    input = keyboard.nextInt();

    int array[] = new int[input]; 

        for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) {
           System.out.println("Enter number: ");
           array[i] = keyboard.nextInt();

            if (array[i] >= max)   
            {   
                max = array[i];  
            } 
            else if (array[i] <= min)   
            {   
                min = array[i];   
            }     
        }   
        System.out.print("\nLargest: " + max);   
        System.out.print("\nSmallest:" + min); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: You dont need `<=` or `>=` just `>` and `<` would suffice.

Comment: I agree @almas shaikh but sometimes, latest current maximum match position is enquired. Sow for those cases. Hence...

Answer (score 2):

Post you read the value, you need to iterate over the array and try to use your logic of mix/max comparison like:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;//change your assignment of 0 as numbers can be negative
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;    
for (int number : array) {//use separate for loop or use the same for loop to which you add numbers in array.
    if (number > max) {   
        max = input;  
    } 
    else if (number < min) {   
       min = input;   
    }     
}
```

With using the same for loop:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;//change your assignment of 0 as numbers can be negative
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    array[i] = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    if (array[i] > max) {   
        max = array[i];  
    } 
    else if (array[i] < min)   
    {   
       min = array[i];   
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this code:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) {
                if (array[i]> max)   
                {   
                    max = array[i];  
                } 
                else if (array[i] <= min)   
                {   
                    min = array[i];   
                }     
            }   
            System.out.print("\nLargest: " + max);   
            System.out.print("\nSmallest:" + min);
```

Comment: Fixed it.. but i'm sure the whole idea is understood.

Answer (score 0):

You can even try this.

```
int max=array[0], min=array[0];

for(int x=0; x<array.length; x++){
    max = array[x]>max?array[x]:max;        
    min = array[x]<min?array[x]:min;
}
```

Set the first array element as min and max first.

Comment: So if `array[x]` is not larger than `max`, then it is automatically smaller than `min`? Interesting.

Comment: `we can do so` No, you can't it would only work, if the array is sorted.